# How to get what resource file is in use?

Tags: java, android

I have multiple resource files in `drawable` folder. Each one changes color of button, I have set it initially to resource file with red color in XML. I want to check by `if` command to see which file is in current use and then set another file (I guess its command is `btn.setBackgroundResource(R.id.drawable.xmfile.xml)`).
So what I want to do is this:

```
if(/* resource file of button currently set == red.xml */){
button.setBackgroundResource(R.id.drawable.blue.xml)
}
```

I will do this for multiple colors so that on each press, button changes its color when pressed for cool effect!

Comment: I think you need to take care of that yourself. If you were even able to read the resource you set, you would receive a random-looking number that serves as the id of the xml. If you want the `Drawable`, try `getBackground()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground()

Comment: you can do it without knowing wich resource is used !! just make a table of resources and every time color is selected increment the index, but you must reset the index to zero when it reash the table length

Comment: The `.xml` is pretty unconventional, as is `R.id.drawable.blue.xml`. A more straightforward way of creating a color resource in `colors.xml` and referencing a particular color resource by `button.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.red))`

Comment: @akodiakson I don't simply have color but a gradient, how could I do it then?

Comment: `...getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red)...`